# Using aggregation within a calculated field in Amazon QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm using Amazon QuickSight and want to create a calculated field which in Tableau would be `sum([Field1])/sum([Field2])`. In QuickSight, I attempted `sum({Field1})/sum({Field2})` but this did not work ("We encountered an error trying to save your calculated field. Please try creating it again."). Simply doing `{Field1}/{Field2}` and then applying the sum aggregation in the visualization stage gives me the incorrect value.

How do I apply a SUM within a calculated field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this is currently not possible with QuickSight: https://answers.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/questions/153/data-field-percent-type-how-to-summarize-it-correc.html

Answer (score 1):

In the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721287/3109349) Greg posted, Quicksight team answer [last year](https://answers.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/questions/153/data-field-percent-type-how-to-summarize-it-correc.html?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=newest): "Hi All, Calculated fields in analysis are available for data sets that use direct query. SPICE data set support is coming soon.".

I tested it today using spice and it work for me.

I used this formula:
`distinct_count(field1) / min(field2)`
and then i used it on a pivot table using other field to group data.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible in Amazon QuickSight. To achieve this you need to add Calculated Field to an Analysis ([as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html)). There are two types of calculated fields: on a data set level and on on analysis level. You can use aggregations in the analysis level calculated field.